# Swift 3 - App crash because file is not yet available in Finder

Tags: swift, finder

Im a building an app which create an audio file (using audio concatenation) and allow playing of the file via a button which appears only if concatenation is successful (case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:).

It is working fine except that the play button appears a little bit to early (the file is not yet visible in the Finder) and, of course, if I push the play button immediately after it appears, the app crash.

What is the right way to make sure it is available in the Finder before playing?

```
func mergeAudioFiles(audioFileUrls: NSArray)
    {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        for i in 0 ..< audioFileUrls.count
        {

            let compositionAudioTrack :AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

            let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: (audioFileUrls[i] as! NSURL) as URL)

            let track : AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

            let timeRange : CMTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeMake(0, 600), duration: track.timeRange.duration)

            try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: composition.duration)
        }

        guard let audioUrl = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Temp.m4a") else {return}
        let mergeAudioURL = audioUrl as NSURL

        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)

            assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
            assetExport?.outputURL = mergeAudioURL as URL
            assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:
            {
                switch assetExport!.status
                {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                    print("failed \(assetExport?.error)")
                    exit(0)
                    break
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                    print("Concatenation audio annulée.")
                    break
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                    print("unknown\(assetExport?.error)")
                    exit(0)

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                    print("waiting\(assetExport?.error)")
                    exit(0)

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                    print("exporting\(assetExport?.error)")

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
                    statusExport = 3
                }
            })
        }
```

In order to play the file I use :

```
 @IBAction func ecoute(_ sender: NSButton)
    {
 do
        {
            guard let resultAudio = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Bailadeur_CompositionTemporaire.m4a") else {return}
            action = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (resultAudio) as URL)
            action.delegate = self
            action.prepareToPlay()
        }catch{}
action.volume = 1
action.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check nil value first

```
guard let audioUrl = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Temp.m4a") else {
   return
}

let mergeAudioURL = audioUrl as NSURL
....
```

Comment: "Guard" method added. But still, it is crashing. I also added "guard" to the player IBAction, but it is not working. I have to mention that it does not crash inside Xcode, only after archiving the app.

Comment: I solved the problem by calling a new function inside "case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:". The play button now appears only after completed status is reached. But it gives an error : CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.

Comment: Problem seems solved. I added a DispatchQueue in order to call the function which is inside "case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:"        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: { () -> Void in self.prepareLecture()})